# Ampscript to convert number into English text

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm curious if there's a way to convert a number (2) into its English spelling ('Two'). I'm inserting the results of a DateDiff function into some content, and I think it might look better spelled out. It doesn't look like any of the FormatNumber() formats have the right output.

Comment: I don't think there is a function for this. Alternatively you could have a data extension populated with number and spellings, and perform a lookup. Since you will have limited use of ssjs in your email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do some custom implementation with apex, bellow is some already existing examples:

https://ayushmangalblog.wordpress.com/2016/04/15/salesforce-currency-to-word-number-to-word/

http://salesforcewithkiran.blogspot.com/2013/05/number-to-words-in-apex.html

http://salesforcemaniacs.blogspot.com/2016/02/convert-currency-into-words-in-salesforce.html

http://weblearningpoint.blogspot.com/2015/02/convert-number-to-words-using.html

I would suggest just reusing some of that code.